# Auto expanding textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, textarea

When a textarea has more text in it than can be shown it will display scroll bars.  How can I make it so that the textarea will expand itself when it has more text than it can display.  My goal is never to have scroll bars appear.  A jQuery solution is preferred.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197115/jquery-detecting-when-we-are-at-the-end-of-text-in-textarea

Comment: But, in answer to your question, http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-plugin-autoresize/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working example:

http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/textarea-expander/index.html

It contains downloadable code as well as implementation instructions.

Answer (score 2):

http://jacklmoore.com/autosize/

```
// Example:
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('textarea').autosize();    
});
```

as simple as it gets. I think 8 ).

Answer (score 0):

I have problems with autosize() for what I'm doing so I use a slightly different method which I'm just posting in case it is useful to others

The behaviour I need is a textarea with its height sized on load and resized when it loses focus (an edit finishes).

```
function updateAddressHeight() {
   var lineHeight=16; //Whatever you need
   address = $("#Address").val()
   lines = address.split("\n");

   $("#Address").height( (lines.length * lineHeight) );
} //funct

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Address").change( function() {
        updateAddressHeight();
    });

    updateAddressHeight();
})
```